# How to count frequencies of certain character in a string?

Tags: regex, r, string

If I have a run of characters such as `"AABBABBBAAAABBAAAABBBAABBBBABABB"`.

Is there a way to get R to count the runs of `A` and state how many of each length ?

So I'd like to know how many instances of 3 `A`'s in a row, how many instances of a single `A`, how many instances of 2 `A`'s in a row, etc.

Answer (score 11):

```
table(rle(strsplit("AABBABBBAAAABBAAAABBBAABBBBABABB","")[[1]]))
```

gives

```
       values
lengths A B
      1 3 1
      2 2 3
      3 0 2
      4 2 1
```

which (reading down the A column) means there were 3 A runs of length 1, 2 A runs of length 2 and 2 A runs of length 4.

Comment: Speed wasn't mentioned as a primary consideration in the question, but there will be faster approaches.

Comment: @akrun yes, `rle` is usually fast but `strsplit` can be slow.

Comment: Yeah, I might use this one for its better output (on account of representing the differing strings by their lengths, and because I doubt speed matters). Or just `table(nchar(strsplit(x, "[^A]+")[[1]]))` since the OP only cares about "A".

Comment: what is the [[1]] at the end doing ?

Comment: `strsplit` returns a list (in this case, since the argument contained only one element, it returns, a list with one element, which contains a character vector that results from splitting it). I wanted the character vector rather than the list it was contained in; `[[1]]` is one way to achieve that.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
 v1 <- scan(text=gsub('[^A]+', ',', str1), sep=',', what='', quiet=TRUE)
 table(v1[nzchar(v1)])
 # A   AA AAAA 
 # 3    2    2
```

Or

```
 library(stringi)
 table(stri_extract_all_regex(str1, '[A]+')[[1]])
 # A   AA AAAA 
 # 3    2    2
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(42)
 x1 <- stri_rand_strings(1,1e7, pattern='[A-G]')

 system.time(table(stri_split_regex(x1, "[^A]+", omit_empty = TRUE)))
 #   user  system elapsed 
 #  0.829   0.002   0.831 

 system.time(table(stri_extract_all_regex(x1, '[A]+')[[1]]))
 #   user  system elapsed 
 #   0.790   0.002   0.791 

 system.time(table(rle(strsplit(x1,"")[[1]])) )
 #   user  system elapsed 
 #  30.230   1.243  31.523 

 system.time(table(strsplit(x1, "[^A]+")))
 # user  system elapsed 
 # 4.253   0.006   4.258 


 system.time(table(attr(gregexpr("A+",x1)[[1]], 'match.length')))
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #  1.994   0.004   1.999 


 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(david=table(stri_split_regex(x1, "[^A]+", omit_empty = TRUE)),
    akrun=  table(stri_extract_all_regex(x1, '[A]+')[[1]]),
    david2 =  table(strsplit(x1, "[^A]+")),
    glen = table(rle(strsplit(x1,"")[[1]])),
    plannapus = table(attr(gregexpr("A+",x1)[[1]], 'match.length')),
         times=20L, unit='relative')

#Unit: relative
#     expr       min        lq      mean    median         uq       max    neval  cld
#   david  1.0000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.0000000  1.000000    20       a  
#   akrun  0.7908313  1.023388  1.054670  1.336510  0.9903384  1.004711    20       a
#  david2  4.9325256  5.461389  5.613516  6.207990  5.6647301  5.374668    20       c 
#    glen 14.9064240 15.975846 16.672339 20.570874 15.8710402 15.465140    20       d
#plannapus 2.5077719  3.123360  2.836338  3.557242  2.5689176  2.452964    20       b
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- 'AABBABBBAAAABBAAAABBBAABBBBABABB'
```

Comment: The timings are interesting.

Comment: @Glen_b I am running it again with the new post

Comment: @akrun i don't think mine will fare particularly well in term of speed :)

Comment: @plannapus with `stringi`, it is hard to compete, but I will update just for making it complete

Comment: @plannapus You are right.  I tried microbenchmark, but I had to stop it as it is taking a long time.  I am updating with the system.time

Comment: @akrun the second function i added seems to be faster (than my previous one at least).

Comment: @plannapus I am still running the system.time on your first function (microbenchmark took a long time).  Can you check the system.time for your second function using the data in the benchmarks?

Comment: @akrun well i m currently at work on a computer running with R 2.14 so no fancy `stringi` for me, but if `x1 <- stri_rand_strings(1,1e7, pattern='[A-G]')` is more or less the same thing as `x1 <- paste(sample(LETTERS[1:7],1e7,r=T),collapse="")`, then `system.time(table(attr(gregexpr("A+",x1)[[1]],'match.length')))` gives me `1.554   0.091   1.640 `

Comment: @plannapus If that is the case, I will abort the run on your first function and do it on the second.  BTW, the first function is very slow, it is running for > 1 hour or so

Comment: @akrun meaning I guess that `regmatches` is the culprit.

Comment: It seems that my second approach is the winner, though I'm not sure if Glens is comparable as it does quite a different thing. Also, why are you adding `cld` underneath? You can keep it in the same place as the rest I guess. There is enough room and it will be more readable.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, your approach is the best.  Regarding Glen's approach, it is a different output.   If he can modify his answer, may be we can use that.   Thanks for formatting, I should have done it better.

Comment: You can maybe use Franks comment under his answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg But, that is a completely different answer.  Frank is not using `rle`

Answer (score 8):

Here's additional way using `strsplit`

```
x <- "AABBABBBAAAABBAAAABBBAABBBBABABB"
table(strsplit(x, "[^A]+"))
# A   AA AAAA 
# 3    2    2
```

Or similarly with the `stringi` package

```
library(stringi)
table(stri_split_regex(x, "[^A]+", omit_empty = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here is another way, using the `regmatches` and `gregexpr` combo, to extract regexes:

```
x <- "AABBABBBAAAABBAAAABBBAABBBBABABB"
table(regmatches(x,gregexpr("A+",x))[[1]])
#   A   AA AAAA 
#   3    2    2
```

Or in fact, since `gregexpr` keeps the length of the captured substring as attribute, one could even do, directly:

```
table(attr(gregexpr("A+",x)[[1]],'match.length'))
# 1 2 4 
# 3 2 2
```

Comment: I updated the benchmarks.  Your version is faster among the base R functions

Comment: I tried creating a random sample of 100 with replacement and as expected end up with a mix of "A"s  and "B"s. I think in doing so I have created more problems as I now appear to have 100 individual strings. Was the a bad idea ?

Comment: If you want to create a random sample of 100 A or Bs with replacement you might either use @akrun `stringi`-based technique (see his answer) or the `base` way: `paste(sample(c("A","B"),100,replace=TRUE),collapse="")`