# How to select rows that don't have a zero in 3 consecutive columns?

Tags: r, loops

I have 9 columns: var2008, var2009, var2010, var2011, var2012, var2013, var2014, varID and varps.
The columns var2008 to var2014 can have the values 0, 1 and 2. I need to find the rows (or actually the ID numbers, varID) where 3 consecutive variables (var2008 to var2014) are not 0. If this is the case varps is 1.

```
dat1$ps <-0
r <- nrow(dat1)
k <- ncol(dat1)-4

for(i in 1:r){
 for(j in 1:k){
  if ((dat1)[i,j] !=0 & (dat1)[i,j+1] !=0 & dat1[i,j+2] !=0)
   {dat1$varps = 1
   }
  }
}
```

When i run this script i don't get any errors, but the varps doesn't change to 1 if the condition is satisfied. The varps is now 1 for every row.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Please provide an example of your data.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you post the output of `dput(head(dat1))`

Comment: Another question today used the rle function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023902/how-to-count-frequencies-of-certain-character-in-a-string

Comment: @lawyeR many used answers on SO used `rle` function. I think in the question you linked the `rle` was unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

You can call `rle` on each row, looking for sequences of 3 or more consecutive non-zero values (thanks to @DavidArenburg for the `any` trick!):

```
dat$varps <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
  r <- rle(x != 0)
  any(r$lengths[r$values] >= 3)
}) * 1
```

Now you can check out some rows where there are three or more consecutive non-zeros:

```
head(dat[dat$varps == 1,])
#   var2008 var2009 var2010 var2011 var2012 var2013 var2014 varps
# 2       2       1       1       2       2       0       2     1
# 3       2       2       1       2       0       2       2     1
# 5       0       2       1       2       2       1       2     1
# 6       1       2       2       2       0       1       0     1
# 7       0       1       2       1       1       1       1     1
# 8       2       2       1       2       2       0       0     1
```

And you can also check out some rows where there are not three or more consecutive non-zeros:

```
head(dat[dat$varps == 0,])
#    var2008 var2009 var2010 var2011 var2012 var2013 var2014 varps
# 1        0       2       2       0       0       1       1     0
# 4        1       0       2       2       0       1       2     0
# 9        0       1       0       2       1       0       1     0
# 12       0       2       1       0       2       0       2     0
# 13       1       0       2       0       0       0       2     0
# 15       0       0       0       0       0       0       1     0
```

Data:

```
set.seed(144)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:2, 700, replace=TRUE), 100))
names(dat) <- paste0("var", 2008:2014)
```

Comment: Of course you could do `rle(x==0)` and `FALSE %in% r$values`  :-)

Comment: I also think you over-complicated this `rle` implementation, you could just do `r <- rle(x==0) ; any(r$lengths[r$values] >= 3)`